# Configure the audio output of chrome

Tags: google-chrome, audio, hdmi

I had been playing video via HDMI out, and now I've disconnected it, but chrome is still sending the audio to the HDMI device. How can I change it?

Comment: Solved. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows:

Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Sound.

Your audio devices are listed there, and the HDMI device has been set to default when you plugged the HDMI device in.

Change the your standard output to the default.

Now restart chrome, and it should work.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to use not the default audio device?

Answer (score 4):

In Linux:

You can use `pavucontrol` to change the audio device of chrome or other applications:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
pavucontrol
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you [edit] your answer to say *how* OP would achieve this using pavucontrol?

Comment: How would this work with pipewire?

Comment: Open up Pavucontrol and Click the “Configuration” button. Then, look through the list of sound devices on screen and find the one you want to turn off. https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/manage-audio-devices-on-linux-pavucontrol/ > Disabling audio devices

Comment: Any idea if there is a way to select it from the browser tab itself?

Comment: This tool can't see my HDMI output which Sound Configuration can see.