# Chrome browser - set specific audio output device

Tags: windows, google-chrome, audio

By default chrome uses the default audio device (related question here: [Configure the audio output of chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/508574/configure-the-audio-output-of-chrome)). But my question is: How would I configure another audio output device, **not** the default device as the chrome output device?
This would be useful in a situation where I have two wireless headsets for example.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Audio Router` is outdated with Windows 10. You should use the advanced settings of Windows :

[image]

See : https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-sound-settings-windows-10-april-2018-update

Comment: This Windows 10 control panel + VoiceMeeter Banana + VM-Cable at https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm was helpful for me.

Comment: Superb solution. I don't see chrome in the applications listed tough.

Comment: @RémiBenoit Chrome will only be listed, if any sound is played.

Comment: Your sentence is confusing

Comment: In Windows 11 (22H2), these settings have moved to System > Sound > Volume mixer > Apps.

Answer (score 4):

This is not supported yet.
A draft from the W3C has been drafted on November 2018,
[Audio Output Devices API](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-output/),
but may take years to be implemented in the browsers.

There are free third-party programs which might help here:

- [Audio Router](https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router/)
  (free) which can be downloaded for
  [64-bit](https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router/releases/download/v0.10.2/AudioRouter-0.10.2.zip)
  and
  [32-bit](https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router/releases/download/v0.10.2/AudioRouter-0.10.2-32bit.zip).
- [VoiceMeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm)
  (Donationware)

These products are reviewed in the article
[How To Use Different Audio Devices For Different Applications In Windows](https://www.itechtics.com/route-audio-pc/) .

Comment: Audio router doesn't work with Chrome, Chrome crashs.

Comment: @A-312: You could signal the problem on [Audio Router site](https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router/issues).

Comment: it's chrome issue : https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router/issues/105

Comment: For future readers: The current workaround is changing the compatibility to anything else in Google Chrome's properties. It might revert back, but using "Change settings for all users" may keep it from happening.

Answer (score 2):

[AudioPick](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/audiopick/gfhcppdamigjkficnjnhmnljljhagaha?hl=en) works by scanning the DOM for `<video>` and `<audio>` elements and then calling [`setSinkId`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/setSinkId). It doesn't work for `<video>` and `<audio>` elements, such as `new Audio(...)`, that haven't been inserted into the DOM.

I think you might be able to write a userscript or extension that monkey patches `Audio`, `document.createElement("audio")` and `document.createElement("video")` so that they select your desired `sinkId`.

Or a quick hack would be to write a script that adds all `audio` and `video` to the DOM so AudioPick is able to find them.